# How to administer scheduledjobs in powershell 3?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

According to documentation, get-scheduledjob only returns scheduled jobs where owner is the current user. Other scheduled job commandlets like set-scheduledjob also only work for scheduled jobs where owner is current user. This makes it impossible for non owners to get job status, modify the job (such as setting other credentials), etc.

In a proper IT organization, I'm going to say its crucial for these jobs to allow adminstration from various administrators.

Am I missing some way to administer, review results, etc (other than looking directly at the powershell output files in the owner's appdata)?

To clarify - I'm looking for a method to work with Powershell created and administered **ScheduledJobs**. If you modify the scheduled task that executes the scheduled job through the UI, schtask or other scheduled task specific tool, you'll get unexpected results. If you change owner/credentials, the scheduled task will fail. You can use UI/schtasks to change schedule without causing any problems. In addition to changing owner, I want to get at the results of get-job in order to monitor the jobs progress.

Comment: I have filed connect suggestion, vote for it if you need this functionality... 

https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/780966/server-wide-scheduledjobs-should-allow-for-non-creator-owner-to-administer-them#details

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have ever been able to get this to work using Powershell was by invoking the schtask.exe utility:

Note: "/U" is for local administration and "/RU" is for remote administration, also "/S" is not needed with working locally.

Create by importing an XML previously exported from Task Scheduler

```
[string]$string = 'schtasks.exe /create /RU yourdomain\username /RP $password /TN Task-Name /XML "D:\Path\To\ExportedXML.xml" /S ServerName'
```

Delete:

```
[string]$string = 'schtasks.exe /delete /RU yourdomain\username /P $password /TN Task-Name /S ServerName /F'
```

Query:

```
[string]$string = 'schtasks.exe /query /RU yourdomain\username /P $password'
```

Run Locally:

```
Invoke-Expression -Command $string
```

Run Remotely:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {$string}
```

Comment: I think there's still a problem with this approach, same problem as with the task scheduler UI. The state of this job is located in

C:\Users\{jobowner}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs

this state is required for the job to run properly. If you change the owner via UI or the schtasks exe it won't move that state and the job just errors.

It seems to me to be a pretty big hole. Joe Admin creates some maintenance tasks, lets them run for a while, and then quits. New Admin has no way to get at the tasks without doing some serious hacking...

Comment: Here's a decent write-up that appears to cover this issue:
[link]http://janegilring.wordpress.com/2012/05/28/working-with-scheduled-tasks-from-windows-powershell/

Excerpt: 
_"...to retrieve the results of the job, not by looking in the XML-files, but by using the Get-Job cmdlet. There is a gotcha to be aware of regarding this. If you open a new PowerShell session and run Get-Job, the scheduled jobs created using the PSScheduledJob cmdlets will not be available. You have to first import the PSScheduledJob module and then run Get-Job. By using Receive-Job we can get the results from our job"_

Comment: I read this, and have tested to be sure, but it only works for the user who created /is the owner of the job. The important bit is part where he identifies that the state of the job is stored to the user's appdata folder. I think we're just out of luck here and will have to write something to at least get status out of xml files. Ugly...

"We can see that the job is stored in a separate folder in the current user`s AppData-folder:"

Comment: Apparently, as you've seen, background jobs are hard-coded in PS to only exist in the creating users' session. That sucks.

Long shot, but [this guy](http://www.petri.co.il/export-import-powershell-scheduled-jobs.htm) has written a custom module that may either help you....or increase your frustration levels to hostage-taking levels. YMMV, of course ;)

Comment: One could use the article you pointed out to create a "migrate" type script used to change a scheduled job over to another user as owner. This would potentially solve one portion of the problem (what to do to get scheduled job running again when a previous owner's account has been deactivate). Still no help on how to monitor the scheduled jobs though. I think only way is to try and import-clixml from the appdata path and essentially reconstruct manually the results you'd see from get-job. When I have  alittle time I will try this these.

Comment: @JorgeSandoval Perhaps PS v3 ScheduledJobs are not the right tool for what you're wanting to do?

Comment: Sorry missed this comment back when. I agree with you. Its just a shame that they had such a well thought out feature with next to no IT administration traction. Why spend time to build out automation, when you know its tied to your user profile on a given machine? 

good for the one man hero squad. bad for best-practices and institutional memory...

Comment: As much as it limits the scriptomagical monitoring of scheduled jobs, it's probably by design. Allowing one user to create a scheduled job that runs under their personal credentials and then allowing another user to interact with it under different credentials would be kind of a bad thing. Tantamount to someone logging in with another persons password. If several administrators need to share administrative duties on something as its *owner*, it needs to be set up to run under a shared account (e.g local Admin account), or (in a pinch) as an interactive service account.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a few PowerShell scripts for managing scheduled tasks (they use the TaskService COM object):

[Rename Scheduled Tasks in Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, and Windows Vista](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/scripting/powershell-script-rename-tasks-140368)

[How-To: Use PowerShell to Report on Scheduled Tasks](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/windows-powershell/how-to-powershell-scheduled-tasks-140978)

[Updating a Scheduled Task's Credentials](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/scripting/updating-scheduled-task-credentials-142570)

Bill

Comment: I've clarified what I'm looking for in an edit to original question. Basically, not looking to manipulate/administer standard scheduled tasks, but ScheduledJobs, that fantastic functionality added to Powershell 3 that apparently only works for one user :(